# python LMDB large DBs (Memory Limit Error)

Tags: python, lmdb

I have a large lmdb, about 800K images.
I want to just read the entries one by one.
My code is very simple and looks like this:

```
with env.begin() as txn:
cursor = txn.cursor()
for key, value in cursor:
    print(key)
```

But after reading about 70000 entries it runs out of memory (~10GB).
I have no idea why.
I tried to do like below but it didn't work.

```
for r in range(0,env.stat()['entries']):
if r%10000==0:
    if r!=0:
        txn.commit()
        cur.close()
    txn=env.begin()
    cur = txn.cursor()
    print("Change Change Change "+ str(r))
    sys.stdout.flush()
    if r==0:
        cur.first()
    else:
        cur.set_range(key)
        cur.next()
key, value = cur.item()
```

any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

The error trace could help. I'd check out the `map_size` param. From the [docs](http://lmdb.readthedocs.io/en/release/#environment-class):

> Maximum size database may grow to; used to size the memory mapping. If database grows larger than map_size, an exception will be raised and the user must close and reopen Environment. On 64-bit there is no penalty for making this huge (say 1TB). Must be <2GB on 32-bit.

This would be an example when writing:

```
with lmdb.open(LMDB_DIR, map_size=LMDB_MAX_SIZE) as env:
    with env.begin(write=True) as txn:
        return txn.put(mykey, value)
```

Comment: This is the error log:

slurmstepd: Job 1008515 exceeded memory limit (65537464 > 65536000), being killed
slurmstepd: *** JOB 1008515 ON mmm269 CANCELLED AT 2016-05-18T15:09:41 ***
slurmstepd: Exceeded step memory limit at some point.
slurmstepd: Exceeded job memory limit

this thime I allocated 64 GB of ram, but again it happened.

the total size of my DB is 596 GB.